# jquery click event with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, list, autocomplete, click

Im trying to attach a simple click event with jquery autocomplete. This is the code Im using:

```
$("#term").autocomplete({

  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
      dataType: 'JSONP',
      data: {
        format: 'json',
        q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=' + escape(request.term) + '"'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {
          return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };
        }));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I would like to be able to click the list item which will then trigger another request (ea populated another list) I want to do this with the jquery click event, so far no good, see this [LINK](http://jsbin.com/epikim/5/edit)

Comment: I had a similar problem. posted the answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158246/firing-the-select-event-on-click-for-jquery-autocomplete/12220921#12220921

Answer (score 4):

You can use [select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event in autocomplete.

```
$("#term").autocomplete({
     select:function(event, ui){
          // do your things here
      },

  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
      dataType: 'JSONP',
               data: {
        format: 'json',
        q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=' + escape(request.term) + '"'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {
          return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };
        }));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Or else you can do like this in your way

```
$(".ui-menu-item a").on('click',function() {
```

See its working [here](http://jsbin.com/epikim/9/edit#source)

Comment: I think I have to get the value of list item, I will look in to it and when it works I will accept answer

Comment: See I have edited now. I had done a mistake too. Try now with my new code .